# React Component Ordering in Dom

Tags: reactjs, dom

I have a react provider containing a number of components that I'm trying to get the order of in the DOM. I'm not concerned with the exact value that orders them but I need to know if one element is before or after another for other logic I need to perform in the provider. My app would look like this:

```
// App.jsx

return (
    <Provider>
        <Element /> // 1
        {showSecond && <Element />} // 2
        <div>
            <Element /> // 7
        </div>
        <Element> // 14
            <Element /> // 21
        </Element>
    </Provider>
);
```

```
// Element.jsx

const orderValue = getMagicOrderValue() // <-- Looking for this
const provider = useContext(providerContext);

useEffect(() => {
    provider.add(orderValue);
    return () => { provider.remove(orderValue); };
}, [orderValue, provider]);

return children;
```

Some of these components maybe nested or come and go per unrelated logic. I plan to report the ordering value to the provider context inside a `useEffect` and I'm not concerned should it change so long as the components then order correctly. Is there a build-in function or value that would help order these elements as they would appear in the dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `useLayoutEffect` can help solve this issue. These are called blocking and in order of the "dom". Using a variable outside the hooks to count the layoutEffect calls and update the order state. However, the cpu could go nuts with all the repeated state updates so `orderingTime` is used to ensure the state can't update more than once per layoutEffect in a single render.

```js
let orderCount = 0;
let orderingTime = 0;

function useOrderingRoot() {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        orderCount = 0;
        orderingTime = Date.now();
    });
}

function useOrdering() {
    const [[time, index], setIndex] = useState(() => [
        orderingTime,
        orderCount + 1
    ]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const order = orderCount++;

        // Prevent cpu thrashing
        if (time === orderingTime) return;

        if (order === index) return;
        setIndex([orderingTime, order]);
    });

    return index;
}
```

I ended up pushing this whole solution to an upstream module and publishing it to npm [make-list-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-list-provider)